# Scrolling RecyclerView Changes Color/Text of Data

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-viewholder, vertical-scrolling

Whenever I scroll the list, all the colors change to different colors and the text from the top of the list jumps to the bottom of the list.

Everything gets fixed when I refresh the fragment, but it changes the data when I scroll. Setting the recyclerview to not recyclable fixed the issue but I want to see if theres another way to go about it, because I still want the view to recycle.

Here is my adapter code:

```
    @Override
public TaskViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
            .inflate(R.layout.trial, parent, false);
    TaskViewHolder viewHolder = new TaskViewHolder(view);
    return viewHolder;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(TaskViewHolder holder, int position) {
    holder.bindHour(holder, mHomeClasses.get(position));
}


     public class TaskViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener{

    //public TextView mDetails;
    public ImageView mPlusButton, mMicButton;
    public TextView mNewTaskButton;
    public TextView mNewExamButton;
    //public TextView[] mTasks =  new TextView[2];
    private ImageView mTakePicButton;
    private ImageView mGallaryButton;
    public RecyclerView mExamsRecyclerView, mTasksRecyclerView;
    public  TextView mExamLabel;
    public  TextView mTaskLabel;

    public TaskViewHolder(View itemView) {

        super(itemView);
        mItemView = itemView;

        mTakePicButton = (ImageView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.takePicButton);
        mGallaryButton = (ImageView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.gallaryButton);

        mMicButton = (ImageView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.micButton);

        mExamLabel = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.examLabel);
        mTaskLabel = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.tasksLabel);

        mExamLabel.setText(R.string.examLabel);
        mTaskLabel.setText(R.string.taskLabel);

        mClassTitle = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.wc1);
        //mDetails = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.details);
        mPlusButton = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.plusButton);

      //  mTasks[0] = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.task1);
       // mTasks[1] = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.task2);
        //mExam1 = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.exam1);
        //mExam2 = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.exam2);

        mNewTaskButton = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.newTaskButton);
        mNewExamButton = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.newExamButton);
        mNewTaskButton.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        mNewExamButton.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

        m  = new MediaPlayer();

        mExamsRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.examRecyclerView);
        mTasksRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tasksRecyclerView);





    public void bindHour(TaskViewHolder holder, HomeClass homeClass){
            Drawable background = mClassTitle.getBackground();
            if (background instanceof ShapeDrawable) {
                ((ShapeDrawable)background).getPaint().setColor(homeClass.getColor());
            } else if (background instanceof GradientDrawable) {
                ((GradientDrawable)background).setColor(homeClass.getColor());
            } else if (background instanceof ColorDrawable) {
                ((ColorDrawable)background).setColor(homeClass.getColor());
            }

        mNewTaskButton.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        mNewExamButton.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

        mExamLabel.setText(R.string.examLabel);
        mTaskLabel.setText(R.string.taskLabel);


        mNewTaskButton.setBackgroundColor(homeClass.getColor());
        mNewExamButton.setBackgroundColor(homeClass.getColor());

        Resources res = mContext.getResources();
        int newColor = mContext.getResources().getColor(R.color.blueGray);
        mPlusButton.setColorFilter(newColor, PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_ATOP);
        mTakePicButton.setColorFilter(newColor, PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_ATOP);
        mGallaryButton.setColorFilter(newColor, PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_ATOP);
        mMicButton.setColorFilter(newColor, PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_ATOP);


        mExamsRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(mContext));
        mExamsRecyclerView.setAdapter(homeClass.getExamAdapter(getAdapterPosition()));

        mTasksRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(mContext));
        mTasksRecyclerView.setAdapter(homeClass.getTaskAdapter(getAdapterPosition()));


        if (mExamLabel.getText().toString().equals(R.string.examLabel) && (mTaskLabel.getText().toString().equals(R.string.taskLabel))){
            Drawable drawable = mContext.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.trial_outline);
            mExamsRecyclerView.setBackground(drawable);
        }

        //mTasks[0].setText(homeClass.getTask1());
        //mTasks[1].setText(homeClass.getTask2());
        mClassTitle.setText(homeClass.getClassName());
        //mDetails.setText("");

        mPlusButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                animation.setDuration(250);
                mPlusButton.startAnimation(animation);
                if (mNewExamButton.getVisibility() == View.INVISIBLE) {
                    mNewTaskButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    mNewTaskButton.startAnimation(AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(mContext, android.R.anim.slide_in_left));
                    mNewExamButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    mNewExamButton.startAnimation(AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(mContext, android.R.anim.slide_in_left));
                } else {
                    mNewTaskButton.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                    mNewTaskButton.startAnimation(AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(mContext, android.R.anim.slide_out_right));
                    mNewExamButton.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                    mNewExamButton.startAnimation(AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(mContext, android.R.anim.slide_out_right));
                }
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

Right, it is "problem" with RecyclerView. He removes view and creates new item. You can keep state of element and restore when recycer wants to create him.

Comment: How would i keep the state of the element and restore. A code snippet would help